# Create a mask input if you use SQL Management Studio 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create  mask input for my tables using SQL Management Studio 2014 but does not seem to work using dynamic mask SQL 2016 which I presume is logical
What is the way to do it for SQL 2014 Management Studio?
Result would be a mask like below:

```
CUST00000-CUST99999 that would increase by 1 every time a customer is created 
VEND00000-VEND99999 - same for vendor etc
```

Comment: The simplest solution here might be to just use an auto increment column and prepend `CUST` to that value when you want to view it this way.

Comment: Seems like a `SEQUENCE` might be what you're after.

Comment: @user12466101 . . . Can you explain what *you* mean by "mask input"?

Comment: Mask input I mean like shown CUST00000-CUST99999

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - autoincrement does not work I believe with SQL Server ? what is the format with identity?

Comment: Also not sure I can have 2 identities in my table - I still want the PK to exist standard and next to it my masked input format. For instance PK 1 and Reference Type =CUST00001

Comment: There was already the answer: **Seems like a SEQUENCE might be what you're after. – Larnu **

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving the logic ,you can implement for your solution .

- Create a Identity column in that table
- Concate the identity value with **CUST** and **VEND**
- Check the value of Identity column once it reached 99999 then reseed it 0.

Syntax are written below

- `ALTER Your_Table add Ident INT Identity (0,1)`
- `CONCAT('VEND',Ident)`
- `DECLARE @Count Int =(SELECT TOP 1 Ident FROM Your_Table ORDER BY DESC)
      IF @Count=99999
      BEGIN 
      DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Your_table', RESEED, 0);

      END`

This is just a logic not the whole solution...

Comment: Thank you all - using the below CUSTOMER AS 'CUST'+RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+CONVERT(VARCHAR,PKID),10)- seems doing the job so far

Comment: Customers and vendors are independent and are not mutual exclusive, in your solution once  "1" was used for vendor it's already exclused for customer, and this is wrong. You can have only one identity column per table while you can use as many sequences as you want for one table, so SEQUENCE and not identity is the solution here